# How to get data-attributes with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I can't seem to find anything related to the problem I'm encountering.

**GOAL**

I'm trying to get the value of a custom data attribute from the button (Web Control) that I created in my code-behind when the button is clicked. I'm referencing [MSDN-Attribute.GetCustomAttribute Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.attribute.getcustomattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2) but I'm not sure if this is appropriate for what I'm trying to do.

My current click sub is below but does not function.

**Default.ascx**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="itemWrapper" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemsPlaceholder" runat="server" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Default.ascx.vb (Code-behind)**

```
Protected Sub Items_Load()
  Dim dynamicID = "13"
  Dim itemBtn = New Button()
      itemBtn.Attributes.Add("data-custom-id", dynamicID) '<- Custom attribute I want to get
      itemBtn.UseSubmitBehavior = False
      itemBtn.Text = "select"
      itemBtn.ID = "Button_" & dynamicID
      AddHandler itemBtn.Click, AddressOf ItemSelectBtn_Click
      itemsPlaceholder.Controls.Add(itemBtn) 
End Sub

Public Sub ItemSelectBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  Dim clickedBtn = DirectCast(sender, Button),
      clickedBtnID As String = clickedBtn.Attributes("data-custom-id")

      Console.WriteLine("this button's ID is " & clickedBtnID)
End Sub
```

**HTML OUTPUT**

```
<div id="Content_C001_itemWrapper">
  <input type="button" 
   name="ctl00$Content$C001$1"
   value="select"
   onclick="target = '_blank';__doPostBack('ctl00$Content$C001$1','')"
   data-custom-id="13">
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

This was the simplest answer. Not sure why this wasn't working but as @zgood suggested to get the attribute. VB.NET uses `Attributes("attribute-name")` and not `Attributes["attribute-name"]` like in C#. Just an FYI.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Where do you add `itemBtn` to the page?  Wouldn't the value be in that control's `Attributes` since that's where you set it?

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot to add in my placeholder to add the itemBtn control. I've updated my question.

Comment: Ok, that's one step.  Still, is the value in `Attributes` where you put it?

Comment: Can't you get the attributes like this - `clickedBtn.Attributes["data-custom-id"]`? [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.attributes?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_WebControls_WebControl_Attributes)

Comment: I'm assuming the value is in `Attributes` when I set it with a hard coded value in the code behind.

Comment: I've tried this as @zgood pointed out and I don't get an error but I also don't the value of the attribute.

Comment: Why not `itemBtn.ID = "Button_13"` And then get the ID from the sender in `ItemSelectBtn_Click` Or a `CommandArgument`?

Comment: Good point @VDWWD. I'll try this now.

Comment: @cpt-crunchy Ya I forgot what the VB syntax was